# Markdown formatting - anchor tag syntax here?

Tags: discussion, support

I am trying to get a little fancy with some formatting to include some inline anchors within the body of my Question so I can add links that would allow jumping past sections of my Question Body that impatient readers want to skip past.  I have tried variations of:
 
`[go to target](#target) ... body text ... <a id="#target"></a>` 
and
`[go to target](#target) ... body text ... <a name="#target"></a>` 
and
`[go to target](#target) ... body text ... "#target"`
and other suggestions as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5319754/cross-reference-named-anchor-in-markdown), but so far I have not been able to get any of these methods to work on History:SE so I'm either missing something obvious, doing something wrong, or the Markdown on History:SE doesn't support in-page links to anchor tags (?)

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried using in-page links to anchor tags on History:SE, but from what I've read, it should be possible.

---

**EDIT**

However, having tried several tests (check the edit history for more details!), when I view the page source it looks like the destination anchor is being stripped out when the page is rendered.

---

I found the Meta:SE question [What HTML tags are allowed on Stack Exchange sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites), from that it looks like the only attributes allowed on the `<a>` tag are:

```
href=""
title=""
```

Which would explain the problem.

---

So, that would suggest that in-page links actually aren't possible on SE sites.